# How to configure Geb in IntelliJ

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, geb

I am new in Geb and groovy and I start reading  "The Book of Geb" (http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/index.html)
I am trying to configure and run simple script in IntelliJ

1. I download manually the jar files: `geb-core-0.9.2.jar`, `selenium-firefox-driver-2.26.0.jar`, `selenium-support-2.26.0.jar`
2. I open IntelliJ and create new Groovy project "MyTest"
3. In IntelliJ: File -> "Project Setting" and add to the Libraries the 3 jar file I downloaded
4. The Jar files was added to my External Libraries
5. Under MyTest project/Src I create a Groovy Class "MyClass"
6. I add a simple code:

   ```
   import geb.Browser

   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

   class MyClass {

       def browser = new Browser(driver: new FirefoxDriver())
   }
   ```
7. Compile and get the error 
   Groovyc: unable to resolve class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
8. I read in few forms that this is about dependency But I didn't understand how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You generally use a build management tool, such as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/), to handle dependencies and configure Geb in IntelliJ.

Have a look at the Geb example projects on GitHub. I have [one that uses Maven](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/geb-examples) and have created some screen casts to help [get started with Geb](http://qualityshepherd.com/2014/03/screencast-geb-automation-quick-start/).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Brian and using gradle will save you a lot of time for you dependencies management.
But if you use idea, you should also learn how it permit to configure them in project/modules http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html